# Chaining additional .order method on long active record query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a selection of firms I would like to add sortable table columns to a table I am displaying them in.

I have a custom search method, and have added pagination, but am having trouble inserting the .order method

```
 @firms = Firm.search(params[:search], params[:id]).page(params[:page]).per_page(2).order(params[:sort] + " " + params[:direction])
```

being fed from the table column heads

```
.order(params[:sort] + " " + params[:direction])
```

the will paginate method

```
.page(params[:page]).per_page(2)
```

being my custom search method

```
Firm.search(params[:search], params[:id])
```

If i try the chain that I have at the top then I get the error

```
undefined local variable or method `firms' for #<FirmsController
```

Any ideas?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@firms = Firm.search(params[:search], params[:id])
                 .order(params[:sort] + " " + params[:direction])
                 .paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 2)
```

Your order method should go before your paginate method.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might have forgotten to put the `@` on the instance variable somewhere? I don't think this kind of error could be coming from your query, since it's saying it's in the `FirmsController`.